# How do I set a user's voice channel when I have the user's id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to move a user when they react with a watermelon emoji to my embed.

I can get their user id when I use `user.id`, but it doesn't work with

```js
user.id.voice.setChannel("712142435794550894");
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
const check = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("AFK CHECK")
  .setColor(0xFF0000)
  .setDescription("React with a `watermelon ` PLS");

message.channel.send(check).then(sentEmbed => {
  sentEmbed.react("");
})

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
  let msg = reaction.message,
    emoji = reaction.emoji;
  const person = user.id;
  if (emoji.name == '' && user.id != "711388151960043582") {
    message.channel.send("HI")
    user.id.voice.setChannel("712142435794550894");
  }
});
```

How do I move the users based on their id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like voice exists on `GuildMember` (at least as of discord.js 12), so you'll need to do:

```js
message.guild.member(user.id).voice.setChannel("712142435794550894");
```